# Xcode 5 error: Unable to create directory /projectname.build/Objects-normal/i386

Tags: ios, xcode

After I updated to Xcode5, I have 3 Uncategorized errors every time I try to build.

Xcode tells me to Check dependencies

Unable to create directory /projectname.build

and a bunch of compiling error due to this:

error: couldn't create directory /projectname.build/Objects-normal/i386: Permission denied

Tried all the sudo lines I could find online but no help... Any can shine a light on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Xcode is trying to write to the root level of your hard drive, for which it doesn't have permissions. Don't change the permissions of your root folder because of this. Check your Locations preferences. Open Xcode preferences and check the path values in the Locations pref pane. Here are the paths I have:

- Derived Data: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Snapshots: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots
- Archives: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives

Comment: I have the same settings... this has been bothering me for the past 6 hours..I really have no idea what's wrong

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error? Maybe there's a detail I'm missing.

Comment: hmm.. new to stackoverflow... dont 'know how to upload image... here's a link. Thanks a lot for your help! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5056948/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-21%20at%2012.53.47%20AM.png

Comment: That works. Hmm. Try searching your build settings for "path". Choose the project (top item) in the project navigator, then the app under Targets, then Build Settings in the top of the editor, then use the search field.

Comment: Specifically, look at Build Products Path, Intermediate Build Files Path, Per-configuration Build Products Path, and Per-configuration intermediate build files path... make sure those are all relative paths and don't start with "/".

Comment: It works now... Thank you so much! Per-configuration Intermediate Build Files Path were missing... you are awesome!